# Multiple LAN networks on a single Ethernet port?

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, home-networking

I have a question.

When a single Router is connected to 3 or more networks, can a Router know 2 of those different networks through a single Ethernet port/interface or does each network has to be physically separated.

In another words, does each network have to be separated physically on the Router?

I have no idea what VLAN are, but if the above is not possible, than I'm going to guess that's what its for...

Many thanks.

Comment: *3 or more networks* What do you mean telling "network"? physical? protocol? adressing? else? *does each network have to be separated physically on the Router?* On ONE SINGLE router? Yes, they must be connected to separate ports. If they are (somehow) connected to one port you have combined them into one physical network already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not all routers support it but) you can have a single interface/port with multiple addresses (in the same or different subnets/networks) associated with it and a router can route between this networks. These are sometimes called "secondary interfaces".

A VLAN - " virtual LAN" is related, but probably not what you are asking about as this typically involves "physical separation". ( It a bit simplistic, but you can think of VLANS as groupings of related ports which usually can't talk directly to each other. A single port can be part of multiple groups though.)

Comment: I see. Thank you. This also helped me understand what Akina was saying about in the comments grawity's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 802.1Q VLANs are used for this purpose – they tell the router to tag each Ethernet frame with its "VLAN ID" depending on which network it should belong to. A compatible Ethernet switch can be used to split/combine this tagged (multi-VLAN) port into individual untagged (single-network) Ethernet ports.

From the router OS's perspective, each VLAN tag corresponds to a separate 'interface'. If the main port is named `lan` or `eth0`, then you'll have virtual interfaces like `lan.2` or `eth0.5`, each with its own IP subnet and address configuration.

Comment: *each with its own IP subnet and address configuration* ?? 802.1Q VLAN is L2, IP subnet is L3... of course, each separate VLAN may contain its own subnets not interfered with another VLAN's subnets, but it is not a dogma - it is possible to transfer the same subnet via 2 or more different VLANs... or you mean inner router's interface IP?

Comment: @Akina Would you be able to give an answer with some detail and clarification so that a dummy like me as well as those who view this post may be able to understand? I will make sure to give it the best answer if you do so :)

Comment: @tinnick It is too difficult, because 1) I do not understand your real situation, and so 2) I do not understand your task fully. Please try to make your task more detailed.